# Why Yum package can be listed but not removed?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

When I list packages that contain nvidia using `sudo yum list | grep nvidia` I get this list:

```
libnvidia-container-devel.x86_64           1.3.0-1                libnvidia-container
libnvidia-container-static.x86_64          1.3.0-1                libnvidia-container
libnvidia-container-tools.x86_64           1.3.0-1                libnvidia-container
libnvidia-container1.x86_64                1.3.0-1                libnvidia-container
libnvidia-container1-debuginfo.x86_64      1.3.0-1                libnvidia-container
nvidia-container-runtime.x86_64            3.4.0-1                nvidia-container-runtime
nvidia-container-runtime-hook.x86_64       1.4.0-2                nvidia-container-runtime
nvidia-container-toolkit.x86_64            1.3.0-2                nvidia-container-runtime
nvidia-docker.x86_64                       1.0.1-1                nvidia-docker
nvidia-docker2.noarch                      2.5.0-1                nvidia-docker
nvidia-query-resource-opengl.x86_64        1.0.0-2.el7            epel
nvidia-query-resource-opengl-lib.x86_64    1.0.0-2.el7            epel
nvidia-texture-tools.x86_64                2.0.8-13.el7           epel
nvidia-texture-tools-devel.x86_64          2.0.8-13.el7           epel
pcp-pmda-nvidia-gpu.x86_64                 4.3.2-7.el7_8          updates
```

As you can see there are multiple packages containing nvidia. I select one, for example `nvidia-docker`.
Then I try to remove this package using `sudo yum remove nvidia-docker` or `sudo yum remove nvidia-docker.x86_64` but it doesn't work.

The package is not removed. How to remove this package?

My System:

> NAME="CentOS Linux" VERSION="7 (Core)" ID="centos" ID_LIKE="rhel
> fedora" VERSION_ID="7" PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
> ANSI_COLOR="0;31" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
> HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
>
> CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7" CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
> REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum list` lists all *available* packages, while `yum list installed` only lists *installed* packages.

So you should try the command `yum list installed | grep nvidia`.

Comment: True, package was not installed. I will remove the corresponding repository.